# When using .Net asynchronous sockets, which thread are callbacks called from?

Tags: .net, network-programming, asyncsocket

When you use asynchronous methods like `Socket.BeginConnect` and `Socket.BeginReceive` you pass an `AsyncCallback` delegate.

When these delegates are called, are they called from one of the internal thread-pool threads, or a temporary thread? 
I was thinking for instance in the case you are running a *server*, if you start doing logic in your callback implementation and don't return, will you exhaust the threadpool after a few connections are accepted since you are 'stealing' the thread?

Comment: You can have a look at msdn [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/asynchronous-programming-model-apm)

Comment: I don't think it says, it least I have been looking at it and I couldn't see the answer.

Comment: A hint in the doc linked by Pavel, when describing the CompletedSynchronously property: "A value that indicates whether the asynchronous operation completed on the thread used to call BeginOperationName instead of completing on a separate ThreadPool thread." [This article](https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/threads/threadpool.html) by Jon Sket is cleare (scroll to BeginRead (etc)

Comment: Thanks guys. To be honest the information in these comments is virtually enough for an answer if someone wanted to add one.